# jQuery-File-Upload plugin, how do I confirm multiple deletes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I use the jQuery-File-Upload plugin for html5 file uploads in batches. Now, to delete (or cancel) a selection of multiple files, it all works well.

To delete one particular file, I use this, and it works well:

```
.on('fileuploaddestroy', function (e, data) { return confirm("Are you sure?"); })
```

Now, when I'm about to delete multiple files, the `confirm` is called for each row of file, and that's surely NOT it! What I need is to have only one `confirm` for all the files in the batch. I've struggled quite a bit to find where and how to fix this code, and will surely appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for that information on how to confirm before deleting individual files.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same need to confirm individual and global delete, with only one confirm for the global one.  I finally found a solution with the mouseup event :

```
var deleteMouseDownFired = false;
var globalDeleteConfirmed = false;

$(".main-delete").mouseup(
    function() {
        deleteMouseDownFired = true;
        globalDeleteConfirmed = confirm("Delete selected files ?");
    }
);

$(".main-delete").click(
    function() {
        deleteMouseDownFired = false;
        globalDeleteConfirmed = false;
    }
);

$('.fileupload').bind(
    'fileuploaddestroy',
    function (e, data) {
        if(deleteMouseDownFired) {
            if(globalDeleteConfirmed) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return confirm("Delete this file ?");
        }
    }
);
```